# ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints: flow (missing) in Alpine Linux

Tags: docker, flowtype, alpine-linux

I'm trying to install the "flow" package in my Docker image:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache --repository https://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing flow
```

It was working fine until yesterday (it seems they have updated the edge repository yesterday) and removed the Flow package (Don't know the reason):

```
Step 5/16 : RUN apk add --no-cache --repository https://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing flow
 ---> Running in 0b4a87861307
fetch https://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  flow (missing):
    required by: world[flow]
```

Is there any solution for this ? Couldn't find it in community either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems the `flow` Alpine package was unmaintained, and was indeed removed yesterday:
https://git.alpinelinux.org/aports/commit/?id=81a4c6c5967b97fbaacac401077888c05c4924eb

The package was introduced to Alpine `edge/testing` on July 2018, resolving the following Github issue:  https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/1605

It seems it hasn't qualified to a community/main since.

Sadly, when a package is removed from Alpine repositories, the change quickly propagates to all mirrors, so it probably doesn't live in any Alpine repository at the moment. If it is critical to your workflow, you could try recovering an old package version from some Alpine image that has it, if you can find such an image by scanning through DockerHub or Github, but this is very far from ideal. Alternatively, you could try building Flow yourself from source.

I would suggest filing an issue at the Flow Github repository: either revive the existing linked issue, or add a new one of your own. Good luck!